# Filtering WordPress title (wp_title())

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, filtering, title

My title tag is composed of wp_title() function. However, on one particular page, it includes my custom taxonomy name, which I'd like to remove from the title.

My custom taxonomy is named "serie". So let's say the user clicks on "XHTML and CSS" tutorial serie, he'll get this :"XHTML and CSS | serie | website-name"

That "serie" (which is the custom taxonomy name) sticks out, so I'd like to know how would I filter it out, so that's it's just "XHTML and CSS | website-name". I have created "XHTML and CSS" in Admin Panel under my "serie", so for example "serie" would be "XHTML and CSS", "C++", "PHP", ...

I used this function to filter it out, but it doesn't seem to work (note: template it loads for that particular page is taxonomy-serie.php) :

```
function tutorials_wp_title( $title, $sep ) 
{
    global $page, $paged;
    $title = NULL;
    $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
    $current_serie = $term->name;
    $sep = '|';
    if ( is_page_template( 'taxonomy-serie.php' ) ) 
    {
        $title .= "$current_serie $sep ";
        $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'tutorials_wp_title');
```

Comment: `if ( $current_serie != 'serie' ) { $title .= "$current_serie $sep "; }` ?

Comment: Can you add a bit more clarification?

Answer (score 2):

Seemed you tried to use the deprecated `wp_title` hook after 4.4.

See my another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34268098/2544762

If you are using WordPress 4.4+, try the following piece of code:

```
function tutorials_wp_title( $title, $sep ) 
{
    global $page, $paged;
    $title = array();
    $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
    $current_serie = $term->name;
    if ( is_page_template( 'taxonomy-serie.php' ) ) 
    {
        $title []= "$current_serie $sep ";
        $title []= get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'tutorials_wp_title');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function tutorials_wp_title( $title, $sep ) 
{
global $page, $paged;
$title = NULL;
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;
$current_serie = $term->name;
$sep = '|';
if ( is_page_template( 'taxonomy-serie.php' ) ) 
{
    $title .= "$current_serie $sep ";
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
}
$pos = strpos($title, "serie |");
if ($pos !== false) {
   $title = str_replace("serie |", "", $title);
}
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'tutorials_wp_title');
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more clarification?