# wp_title filter takes no effect on the <title> tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I just added the following filter in my theme `functions.php` file:

```
function change_the_title() {
    return 'My modified title';
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'change_the_title');
```

And in my `header.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class();?>>
```

Then, I found the title of my page did **NOT** change! And the title tag was injected in the `wp_head` function.

More, if I call the function `wp_title` manually in the header, it does return the expected value.

What's the matter? How can I work around it?

---

Addition: My WordPress version is 4.4.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I finally found out that the WordPress core code was changed, see the below piece of code.

```
/**
 * Displays title tag with content.
 *
 * @ignore
 * @since 4.1.0
 * @since 4.4.0 Improved title output replaced `wp_title()`.
 * @access private
 */
function _wp_render_title_tag() {
    if ( ! current_theme_supports( 'title-tag' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<title>' . wp_get_document_title() . '</title>' . "\n";
}
```

So, after 4.4, the core do not inject the `wp_title` result into the header `<title>` tag, but do the same thing with a new function `wp_get_document_title`.

So instead, we can do the same thing by:

*1. change the title directly:*

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'change_the_title');
function change_the_title() {
    return 'The expected title';
}
```

*2. filtering the title parts:*

```
add_filter('document_title_parts', 'filter_title_part');
function filter_title_part($title) {
    return array('a', 'b', 'c');
}
```

For more, see the details here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_document_title/

> PS: Looking into the source of function `wp_get_document_title` is a good idea, the hooks inside which tells a lot.

Comment: Thank you @fish_ball just perfect answer.

Comment: FINALLY! Every other post about this topic is wrong- nailed it! Thanks!

Comment: Man... Sometimes I hate WordPress. Why was this so hard to find?

Comment: @JonathanGruber be a contributor, and vote me up, then you will love it again, haha!

Comment: `pre_get_document_title`  does not work for some themes., any idea why. ?

Comment: @Adeel I think the theme has to use the new function `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' )` rather than the old function `wp_title`

Comment: patta much obliged mate. have been struggling with deprecated wp_title till now

Comment: Since WP 5.8 there is a new filter `document_title`, which filters title after all other filters have been applied (if `pre_get_document_title` is not used)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its necessary to inject the variable, but try this.

```
function change_the_title($title) {
    return 'My modified title';
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'change_the_title');
```

Comment: Thank you, but I finally found the solution myself.

Comment: Great, didn't knew about it :)

Answer (score -3):

you are missing `title` in your `head` tag, Add In `<head>` tag

`<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'left'); ?></title>` your wp_filter will work normally.

Comment: Thank you, but I finally found the solution myself.

Comment: We don't need to do so, because the core function `wp_head()` will do the injection.