# How to change the title of a web page in Wordpress and Enfold theme

Tags: wordpress

I use Wordpress and Enfold theme for a web site. Currently the title for all the web pages is rendered in the format *SITE_TITLE | PAGE_TITLE*.

I would like to be able to change the title for a specific page into *PAGE_TILE* (i.e. strip the *SITE_TITLE* and the separator from the current format) without changing the theme files to make sure updates won't override changes. Is there any possibility to do that?

Note: I tried to use filters, namely [wp_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) and this was only able to change the *PAGE_TITLE* string and the page would still show the *SITE_TITLE* and the separator, so this approach is not good.

Comment: Read : (Removing site name from title? (6 posts))[https://wordpress.org/support/topic/removing-site-name-from-title]

Comment: Doesn't apply to my case.

Answer (score 1):

Replace what you have with this:

```
 wp_title( '&#124;', true, 'right' );
```

Then, in functions.php (or in a child Theme functions.php; normal caveats apply), add the following:

```
function wpse95147_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_single() || ( is_home() && !is_front_page() ) || ( is_page() && !is_front_page() ) ) {
        $title = single_post_title( '', false );
    }
    if ( is_front_page() && ! is_page() ) {
        $title = esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse95147_filter_wp_title' );
```

This is an answer from : [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95152/93309)

Comment: Sorry, as I wrote in the question, I already tried using the wp_title filter and this solution doesn't work. As I mentioned in the question, I use the Enfold theme which might alter the way the title is rendered. Secondly, I don't want to alter the header.php or any other theme file because the updates might revert the changes.

Comment: @lucim if the header(title) is a part of your theme & you don't want to alter the php file then there is no solution.

Comment: No problem, if you don't want to make changes in your actual theme in fear of losing changes on yheme update you can go with child theme. That's why child themes actually are .... have a read about child themes here https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a simple trick. Just check in your header.php file that on which page you are, if you are on your desired page use `wp_title();` where you want to have only Title and separator and pite title then use `wp_title('|', true, 'right');` on all other pages you can follow your already being used method. In code it will look something like shown below

```
<?php if(is_front_page()){?>
<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<?php }else {?>
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
<?php } ?>
```

In this way you can get your desired format, in above code it will show just page title on front page and will show website title separator and page title on all other pages. You can modify this code according to your needs and it will work for you.

Comment: OP says : "I don't want to alter the header.php or any other theme file because the updates might revert the changes."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that theme, but WordPress 4.4 introduced [a new way to handle page titles](https://www.developersq.com/change-page-post-title-wordpress-4-4/), replacing `wp_title` for any theme that declares support for `'title-tag'`. If your theme does that, you need to use either the `document_title_parts` hook to change all of the title's parts (what gets separated by | characters). Or, use the `pre_get_document_title` hook to modify the title as one big string.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34268098/2271 for more details.