# How do I generate custom title tag in wordpress manually?

Tags: wordpress

Here's the sample code:

```
<title>Reviews <?php wp_title();?><?php echo " (".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'imdb_year', true).")"; ?></title>
```

And How do I create the wp_title() function above correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This will change the title.

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'change_the_title');
function change_the_title() {
    return 'The expected title';
}
```

So basically you can add extra logic inside it to change on specific pages, categories, post_types, etc..

> [Wordpress 4.4+: wp_title filter takes no effect on the `<title>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266520/wordpress-4-4-wp-title-filter-takes-no-effect-on-the-title-tag)